# what is the difference between main(String... s) and main(String[] s)?

Tags: java

```
class Test{
    public static void main(String... s){
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}

class Test{
    public static void main(String[] s){
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

What is the difference between above two syntax of `main()` declaration?

Does Java has any special need to have variable length argument?

Comment: what about this 
`public static void main(String[]... a){}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No difference (when you run the program from the command line, i.e. what the main method is used for). The first variant appeared after Java 5 introduced [varargs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html).

In short, varargs allows you to pass a variable number of arguments to a method. For the method body the arguments are grouped into an array. Like `Test.main("foo", "bar")` instead of `Test.main(new String[] {"foo", "bar"})`. The compiler does the array creation for you behind the scene.

Comment: Your second paragraph seems to indicate a difference, contrary to your first sentence...

Comment: no difference .. when you run the program from command line, what the main method is intended for. Added clarification

Comment: does this type of variable length argument can be used elsewhere?

Comment: i means that, there must be any requirement that's why java created this `...` . Isn't it?

Comment: It was added to simplify some method invocations

Answer (score 6):

The only difference is if you call `main` directly from other Java code. The first form allows you to write:

```
Test.main("first", "second", "third");
```

whereas the second would require you to create an array explicitly:

```
Test.main(new String[] { "first", "second", "third" });
```

Personally I don't think I've ever seen the first form used - calling `main` from other code is pretty rare. There's nothing *wrong* with it though.

Comment: Interestingly the JNI signatures for the two forms are identical. 
(I care about that as I explicitly call `Class.main()` for loading java plugins to C++ via JNI).

Comment: And the only mix that doesn't work for me is `main( String[] )` with `Test.main("a","b","c")` --- `main( String... )` with `Test.main( new String[] {"a","b","c"}` seems OK. (Java 1.5.0 on OSX).

Comment: @Michael: Yes, the latter certainly would work. There's nothing special about `main` here - it works the same way as any other varargs method.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference.

In general, `String... s` allows to pass arguments with comma as separator, while the `String[] s` requires an array.
But in the implementation `s` is array in both cases. So `...` is sintactic sugar in a sense.

Answer (score 0):

Variable number of arguments `main(String... s)` was only introduced in Java 5.0.